# Setting PHPs error_reporting level in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

What is the error_reporting integer value to be set in .htaccess to correspond to "E_ALL & !E_NOTICE & !E_DEPRECATED"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are PHP constants, echo it and you will have the value:

```
echo $lev = E_ALL & !E_NOTICE & !E_DEPRECATED
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, try this :

```
echo $lev = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED;
```